# RegexFilter in Log4j2.xml not filtering logs as expected

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I can't seem to get the `RegexFilter` working. I have set up the `log4j2.xml` file as follows:

```
<Console name="prodOutput" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout pattern="[%d] [Org Utility] -- [ITEM1=%X{ITEM1} ITEM2=%X{ITEM2} ITEM3=%X{ITEM3} USERID=%X{USERID} ENV=%X{ENV}]- [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"/>
    <Filters>
        <RegexFilter regex=".*ENV=local.*" useRawMsg="false" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    </Filters>
</Console>

<Loggers>

        <!-- switch off log output from these packages -->
        <Logger name="orgName.package1" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="prodOutput"/>
        </Logger>

        <!-- retain log output for other packages -->
        <Logger name="orgName" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="${sys:logger.out.type}"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="${sys:logger.out.type}"/>
        </Root>

</Loggers>
```

Here's a sample of our log output, but somehow the log from this package `orgName.package1` is not getting picked up the regex, because I can still see the log from this package in the console.

```
[2023-01-03 12:41:56,353] [Org Utility] -- [ITEM1=XX ITEM2=XX ITEM3=XX USERID=@ADMIN ENV=local]- [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29] DEBUG orgName.executeRule [] ...
```

Because when I replace the regex with the trivial `.*`, the output from the package `orgName.package1` is not shown in the console.

The value of `ENV` in `ThreadContextMap` is `local`, so I'm expecting the log output to be `... ENV=local ...` & it indeed is, as shown in the console. But this log is somehow not getting detected by the regex.

Is there a setting or configuration I missed out on? Or perhaps I had miswrote the regex? But I had double-checked my regex on regex101.com & the test-cases I wrote passed, here's a [sample](https://regex101.com/r/NHYTlq/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand why the `RegexFilter` doesn't work, it's because I'm trying to apply a regex on the logger & not the message.

`RegexFilter` is intended to apply regexes on **messages**, i.e. ONLY the part that you define in the `PatternLayout` using the `%m` [Conversion Pattern](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#patterns)), and NOT details associated with the logger (type, time, package, class name etc).

---

### Example

Here is the pattern definition in *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %p %C.%M - %m%n"/>
```

And here is a sample log:

```
2024-03-28T05:40:30,667 INFO com.example.Foo.doSomething - This is a log message
```

So using the `<RegexFilter>` you can only target the *message* which in this case is:

> This is a log message

ONLY this part will be checked for a *match*.

---

I referenced this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435243/log4j2-regexfilter-pattern-does-not-match) that was very similar to my question.

Hope this serves as a helpful guide to anyone that comes across this, cheers!